plt.xaxis.set_major_formatter ignored
I am trying to customize xticks, but they are completely ignored by python and I can't figure out why.
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import shutil
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv('/var/www/cioffi/wp-content/uploads/2023/11/output.csv',index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])

plt = df.plot(y="P_1_1_2_Tot_1", ylabel="mm", kind="line", title="Precipitazioni", grid=1, figsize=(8,4),xlabel="",rot=90,legend=False)

plt.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=2)) 
plt.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m'))

plt.figure.savefig('/opt/script/cioffi/precipitazioni.png', dpi=150 ,bbox_inches="tight")
shutil.move('/opt/script/cioffi/precipitazioni.png','/var/www/cioffi/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/precipitazioni.png')

They are automatically overwritten in this way:

plt.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=2)) 

is ignored, and I would like it to be every 2 days
plt.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m'))

is ignored, and I would like the day and month to be written for every ticks.

This question can't be answered until you provide a reproducible example with sample data. It is also important to specify the versions of the packages that you are using. The plotting part of your code works fine in matplotlib 3.7.2 and pandas 2.2.1

A remark: writing plt = df.plot(...) is very confusing, as it overwrites plt as imported via from matplotlib import pyplot as plt.  It is highly recommended to use ax = df.plot(...) together with ax.xaxis.set._.... Such would ease comparing your code to examples and tutorials.

Pandas plotting doesn't work well together with matplotlib's date locators and formatters.  You'll need to restart the environment (to get rid of the pesky plt = ....), and directly use matplotlib for plotting: fig, ax = plt.subplots() and ax.plot(df.index, df['P_1_1_2_Tot_1']). ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90) will rotate the tick labels.
